# TYPO3 - “The given subject was not a collection”

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

has anyone ever had an error like that:

```
The given subject was not a collection
```

from `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Validation/Validator/CollectionValidator.php:57` (9.5.13)?

After submitting a form to a controller action this error is thrown before everything is passed to the controller action. The passed form data includes some custom entities used within the submitting template.